# Phusion passenger has crossed maximum instances limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I'm using the following for my rails app.

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 3.0.5
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.5
```

The app sits in a 4GB RAM linux box. I recently upgraded my rails app from 3.0.1 to 3.0.5 for the critical security fix they released last week.

I've been noticing a strange thing. I'm having the following passenger settings in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
PassengerMaxPoolSize 10
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 5
```

But there are 18 rack instances spawned by passenger. Its just one app in the server and there is nothing else. App has become slow in response times. I suspect the extra rack instances (coming out of nowhere) is occupying extra memory.

here is my `free -m` output

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4011       3992         19          0          1         22
-/+ buffers/cache:       3968         43
Swap:         8191       5780       2411
```

Here is my `passenger-status` command output and `passenger-memory-stats` output.

`passenger-status`:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 10
count    = 5
active   = 1
inactive = 4
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current:
  App root: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
  * PID: 6704    Sessions: 0    Processed: 72      Uptime: 9m 58s
  * PID: 6696    Sessions: 0    Processed: 99      Uptime: 9m 58s
  * PID: 6712    Sessions: 0    Processed: 69      Uptime: 9m 57s
  * PID: 6688    Sessions: 0    Processed: 52      Uptime: 9m 58s
  * PID: 6677    Sessions: 1    Processed: 83      Uptime: 11m 28s
```

`passenger-memory-stats`:

```
--------- Apache processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
6470  1     95.5 MB   0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
6471  6470  94.7 MB   0.5 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
6488  6470  378.4 MB  4.6 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
6489  6470  378.0 MB  3.8 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
6774  6470  377.4 MB  3.0 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
### Processes: 5
### Total private dirty RSS: 12.20 MB


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


------ Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize     Private   Name
---------------------------------
6472   87.1 MB    0.2 MB    PassengerWatchdog
6475   100.9 MB   3.2 MB    PassengerHelperAgent
6477   39.4 MB    4.8 MB    Passenger spawn server
6482   70.7 MB    0.6 MB    PassengerLoggingAgent
6677   289.1 MB   114.3 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
6684   287.3 MB   17.2 MB   Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
6688   295.6 MB   82.4 MB   Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
6696   299.2 MB   88.9 MB   Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
6704   299.0 MB   87.3 MB   Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
6712   312.6 MB   113.3 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
23808  1174.7 MB  190.9 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
26271  1767.0 MB  690.0 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
28888  1584.7 MB  177.8 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
32403  1638.5 MB  230.3 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
32427  1573.6 MB  253.4 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
32443  1576.0 MB  234.7 MB  Rack: /home/anand/public_html/railsapp/current
### Processes: 16
### Total private dirty RSS: 2289.34 MB
```

What is going wrong here? Is Rails 3.0.5 starting up extra extra rack apps. Please help.

Comment: If you are only running one app I would set the `PassengerMaxPoolSize` to also be five. It looks like the app is only using five instances, but Passenger is using the other five instances it is allowed to pre-load some instances that are not being used to serve requests.

Comment: possibly related to http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=1016 which is fixed in 4.0.28